# How do I check if array index exists?

Tags: go

I have this variable `cp := [][][][]map[string]float64{}`.

How do I check if the element `cp[1][5][0][7]` is set?

I know I could use something like `val,error := cp[1][5][0][7];` but it does not work (maybe it only works with other variable types).

I am using the code below, BUT I think probably there is a much simpler/nicer way.

```
if ((len(cp) > 0) && (len(cp[1]) > 0) && (len(cp[1][5]) > 0) && (len(cp[1][5][0]) > 0) && (len(cp[1][5][0][7]) > 0) ) {
    os.Println("is set");
}
```

So how can I accomplish this?

Comment: The last `len` check seems to be unnecessary.

Comment: `I know I could use something like val,error := ...`, where do you get that idea? There is no case where a slice or array index returns an error.

Comment: @jimb there is, check the answer to this question.

Comment: The answer has nothing about an error. Yes maps and channels have an optional `value, bool` syntax, but that does not really make sense for a slice which has known bounds.

Comment: @jimb you are wrong again, slice has NO bounds. Array has bounds. And please read the accepted answer, it tells exacly how to check if an element exists using `value,error` sintax.

Comment: A slice _does_ have bounds, `0` and `len(slice)`,  and they are always known at runtime when indexing the slice. The answer shows the `value, bool` (not an error) assignment syntax for a map, not for a slice or array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may be mixing up maps and slices. For maps, you have the syntax:

```
value, ok := mymap[key]
```

Which sets `ok = true` if `key` exists in `mymap`, or to `false` otherwise.

---

There is no such capability for slices in Go; you can only index them, and you have to be in-bounds (or the program will panic). Checking your index vs. the `len` of the slice is the only way.

If you have deeply nested data structures that make this awkward, consider encapsulating this logic in helper functions or a data type (`struct` with methods).